# Compare content of two mysql-database dumps and generate patch sql file

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to mirror a production database to a local environment, perform a few operations on it and have to sync it back to production. Currently I do a database dump using `mysqldump` of the remote database, load it into my local database, use it and when I am finished I dump it again using the same command. I don't alter the structure, but only the contents of the database. Is it possible to generate "the difference" between the two dumps, meaning the sql-commands required to apply the changes back to the production database?

A bit of context why I need this: I use a program which performs a lot of SELECT operations on the database. It is, however, very poorly written, as it waits for every Query to complete and only proceeds execution after that. This works locally, as the delay isn't that big, but over an ssh connection to a remote server, the delay is just too big for this to work efficiently.

There are only read-operations performed on the remote-database, while I edit the local cache, so lost update errors are unlikely. I can't just delete all tables and load the dump though, as that would make the read-only operations fail during the "downtime".

Comment: Anything is possible, however is it a sensible solution? I am not so sure about that

Comment: *Is it possible to generate "the difference" between the two dumps, meaning the sql-commands required to apply the changes back to the production database?* In general - no. Especially when triggers are present.

Comment: @RiggsFolly what would be a sensible solution? It feels hacky to me as well, but what would be your best recommendation?

Comment: Have you thought of looking at the binlog? You may be able to pick the exact changes to the database, even triggered changes from there. I think teher may even be some libraries to assist in processing that file about somewhere